# Image upload for thousands of users

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I am developing an API using Codeigniter. In this API I want to allow people to upload images to their accounts. These images are then made to thumbnails and originals.

I am using the built in Upload and Image manipulation libraries that ships with the framework. It all works very good but I am a bit concerned that there will be problems if thousands of people uploads each day.

Will the vanilla libraries that I use work fine then? Assuming my code is good or do I need to use other ways of handling uploads and image manipulation. Any suggestions?

Does it all perhaps depend on the server setup?

Answer (score 3):

We just tackled a similar problem at my place of work. I hope you can gain some insight from our solution:

We had a legacy structure in place that was causing problems, the system was slowly but surely creeping to a halt and we couldn't figure out why. After some digging around we discovered the issue lay in the number files we had in one directory. We had realised the original code base was placing all thumb-nailed and original images into the same folder and we had reached 68347 files! This was a definite issue. We also realised that the server could slow if multiple users were uploading images, and the server was then handling the upload and also the scaling and cropping of the image.

We have implemented a new solution now, which we feel is robust enough for any future challenges we face. It comes down to three points:
  - a bucketed time-stamped folder structure for images (the directory structure decision is implementing using a strategy pattern, so we can easily create a new strategy if we encounter any problems)
  - handle the upload only at the time of upload
  - thumb-nailing is managed when an image is requested in that size (this happens only once, and whenever the image is first viewed)
  - We moved to the Imagine library to handle the process of cropping and scaling as we found it produced better results than ImageMagik and GD in terms of image quality. [Check it out on Git.](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)

Here is a level of detail around the solution:
  1. **For each type of upload** (logo, user avatar, document, etc) **we would have a base directory** e.g. `/.../uploads/logos/`

1. We would create a new folder for each new day that a file was uploaded e.g. `/.../uploads/20122011/`
2. Within these files we would have a **bucketed folder structure** where no more than 1000 files would be found in each folder e.g. `/.../uploads/20122011/0/` , `/.../uploads/20122011/1000/`, etc.
3. Each image that was uploaded we would **generate a pseudo unique name** (32 chars long), we used md5 of time + a random seed to generate this.
4. At the time of upload, if the image was replacing another, we would update the relevant rows in the database and then remove the orphaned file from the db.
5. The **thumbnailing of the image would be handled at the first request**. We implemented this using the folllowing rules in our http conf file:

   AllowOverride all
           Order Deny,Allow
           Allow from all

   ```
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.(.*)$
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
       RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to/public/thumbnailer.php [NC,L]
   ```

   This would redirect any requests for files that didn't exist that were images to our thumb-nailer. Were any acceptable requests would be handled and new thumbnails would be generated.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! A couple of questions. 1. Why do you not scale the images at the time of upload (I am using 5 sizes)? I am using Amazon S3 does that change anything for the folder structure?

Comment: @Jonathan - You would be performing 5 operations sequentially for every image that is uploaded. This could be necessary overhead, however we theorized that not every image is viewed in all formats, and definitely not straight away to justify all this upfront processing. We therefore decided to minimise overhead during the the upload and move the handling of this action to the first request. It also conserves server space when you start thinking about hundred of thousands of images that may never be requested. With reagrds to S3 , I don't think it does. Hoeever don't quote me on that!

Comment: Ok, I see you point. The API that I am developing will perhaps serve an iOS app (like for example Instagram) and then the images will be "seen" directly after the upload has finished. Is there a way to keep the image resizing on a seperate "thread" so to say?